# Checking if date in table B is between date in Table A before inserting SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, triggers

I have a table called Project with start and end dates. I also have a table called Plan which have its own start and end dates column. But I some way to validate that the Plans start/end date is between the matching Project start/end date.

I dont know if its appropriate to add a check when I create the table or when I insert rows to the Plan table. So far I have tried both with no luck.

The following code gives me an error message no such column. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC5Ai.png

```
%%sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Plan;
CREATE TABLE Plan (
    pID varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    projectID varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
    startDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-12-31',
    endDate DARE NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-12-31'
    CHECK (JulianDay(startDate) <= JulianDay(endDate) AND (startDate >= Project.startDate) AND 
           (endDate <= Project.endDate)),
    PRIMARY KEY (pID, projectID),
    FOREIGN KEY (projectID) REFERENCES Project(projectID)
);
```

Comment: Please post your query as text in the question rather than a link to it as an image

Comment: That model ensures there can be only one plan per project. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: @TheImpaler A project can have many plans. What have I done wrong that ensures only one plan per project?

Comment: @PMolnes Remove the `UNIQUE` keyword in the line `ProjectID varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,`

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you very much! As for the original problem, do you know how I can validate that the plans date is between the projects date?

Comment: @PMolnes You cannot add integrity constraints across joined tables. The only option I can see is to add a trigger that is invoked by the `BEFORE INSERT` and/or `BEFORE UPDATE` events. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you very much for your help! I will try out this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_ins_plan BEFORE INSERT ON Plan
BEGIN
  SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 
          FROM Project p 
          WHERE p.projectID = NEW.projectID AND p.startDate <= NEW.startDate AND p.endDate >= NEW.endDate
        )
        THEN RAISE(ABORT, 'Invalid dates')
    END;  
END;
```

and a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_upd_plan BEFORE UPDATE ON Plan
BEGIN
  SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 
          FROM Project p 
          WHERE p.projectID = NEW.projectID AND p.startDate <= NEW.startDate AND p.endDate >= NEW.endDate
        )
        THEN RAISE(ABORT, 'Invalid dates')
    END;  
END;
```

Also, change the `CHECK` constraint for the dates to:

```
CHECK (JulianDay(startDate) <= JulianDay(endDate))
```

or just:

```
CHECK (startDate <= endDate)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f599367857a3874c3cf52be3d1ec5e6e).